# Can I transfer at Schiphol with less than 2 months on passport?

Tags: airport-transfer

I will be flying from America via Schiphol airport in Amsterdam to my home in Scotland soon. I won't be leaving Schiphol during my layover there. When I leave America, I will have less than two months on my passport. I don't think this will cause me any problems at Schiphol as I'm traveling from a non Schengen country (America) to a non Schengen country (UK) and, as I mentioned, I won't be leaving Schiphol airport. Am I correct in thinking that I can transit through Schiphol with less than two months on my passport? I should add that I'm a British citizen with a UK passport.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is fine.  You won't be able to go through passport control in Amsterdam, but you aren't expecting to want to.  (If, however, your flight is delayed, you won't be able to leave the airport as you would if you had more than three months' validity on your passport.)

Comment: I have always wondered, what is the point in having a passport valid up to date X, if you are required to still have N months of validity left in cases like this...

Comment: @MatteoTassinari For the people who don't fly :-) When voting, around here (Netherlands) your Dutch ID can be expired for a maximum of 5 years. Even though a different law states you must be able to ID yourself just about everywhere with an ID that can't be expired. But unless you have a valid foreign ID with you when you go vote with a lapsed Dutch ID... Best not to think about it too hard.